# jQuery links are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  some jQuery that makes links, but the links are them supposed to trigger more jQuery but they do not, here is the code:

```
$(".divisionLinks").click(function () { 
  $('.show_hide_division').show();
  $('.show_hide_main').html($(this).html()+ " is Selected");
  //Load the division xml
  var xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.load("xml//division//"+ $(this).html() + ".xml");
  theEnvNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ENVIRONMENT');
  //Make the html
  theNewHTML = "<ul>";
    for (i = 0; i<theEnvNodes.length; i++){
    theNewHTML = theNewHTML + "<li><a class=\"environmentLinks\" href=\"#\">";
    theNewHTML = theNewHTML + theEnvNodes[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    theNewHTML = theNewHTML + "</a></li>";
    }
  theNewHTML = theNewHTML + "</ul>"; 
  $('.environmentButtons').html(theNewHTML);
});
$(".environmentLinks").click(function () { 
  $('.show_hide_environment').show();
  $('.show_hide_division').html($(this).html()+ " is Selected");
});
```

So division links work, but the environment links do not.
I have been reading it may be something with jQuery indexing the .environmentLink class. But I do not know, and do not know of a work around.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must use for example:

```
$(".environmentLinks").live('click', function () { 
  $('.show_hide_environment').show();
  $('.show_hide_division').html($(this).html()+ " is Selected");
});
```

or:

```
$("body").on('click', ".environmentLinks", function () { 
  $('.show_hide_environment').show();
  $('.show_hide_division').html($(this).html()+ " is Selected");
});
```

Comment: [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is **deprecated**, have a read of the API. Earlier than jQuery 1.7 [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) should be used, and in 1.7+ [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used.

Comment: You welcome, I make little syntax mistake in `.on()` example, I have edit it :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding the .environmentLinks dynamically, the click event you have doesn't get attached since those links don't exist when the page is loaded. If you're using the latest version of jQuery, use `.on()` to bind the click event to the .environmentLinks links.

```
$("body").on('click', '.environmentLinks', function () { 
  $('.show_hide_environment').show();
  $('.show_hide_division').html($(this).html()+ " is Selected");
});
```

Ideally you want to replace $("body") with a parent element of `.environmentLinks` that's closer to it than the body element.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.

Answer (score 0):

it´s because the enviroment links are generated later and your click function is bound to the DOM, I think.

Try this:

```
$(".environmentLinks").live("click", function(){

 $('.show_hide_environment').show();
 $('.show_hide_division').html($(this).html()+ " is Selected");
});
```

This will "refresh" your click events.